# How to remove unwanted indent at the List of Figures (LoF)

Tags: table-of-contents

**Problem:**

I have an unwanted indent before the content of Figure 2.3 as you can see below.

[image: intend problem]

**Details:**

I think it arose from the multiple lines in the caption since it disappeared in the case of a single line. I use a class being voluntarily provided by some guys in İstanbul Technical University to satisfy the thesis template of institute. A link for this class is given below.

[thesis_itu.cls](https://github.com/ondes/Template-Latex-ITU-Thesis/blob/master/Template-Thesis/thesis_itu.cls)

Also, the specific parts to related the LoF is given from this class to follow easily.

```
\newlength{\LoFparskip}     %% List of Figure parskip 08-05-2006
\setlength{\LoFparskip}{0em}
```

---

```
\newcommand{\LoFspacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.0\defbaselineskip}}               %%\LoFspacing = 1.0*\defbaselineskip 08-05-2006
```

---

```
\newif\if@loflotpagebold\@loflotpageboldtrue % If LOF and LOT page numbers are bold or not - SBÖ
```

---

```
\def\@lofline#1#2#3#4#5{
\vskip 1\p@
\ifnum #1=\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
    \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
    \interlinepenalty\@M \normalsize                    % normalsize font - SBÖ
    \leavevmode %\bfseries                              % sections, subsections, subsubsections unbolded - SBÖ
    \@tempdima #3\relax
    \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
    {#4}\nobreak
    \if@ToCisDotted
    \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\hbox{.}$}                      %cleaders or xleaders is more flush than leaders - SBÖ
    %        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.} \mkern\@dotsep
    %         mu$}
    \fi
    \hfill
    %\nobreak
    %\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\dotfill #5} % Removed - SBÖ \hss #5
    \hfil\nobreak\if@loflotpagebold\bfseries\fi#5 % Added to make the dots come next to the page numbers with bold page numbers - SBÖ
    \par}
\fi}
```

---

```
\newcommand{\firstsubcaption}[2][\empty]% #1 = short caption (optional), #2 = caption 
{%\refstepcounter{figure}
    \refstepcounter{subfigure}
    \ifx#1\empty
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline {\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}{\ignorespaces #2 \relax}}
    \else
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline {\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}{\ignorespaces #1 \relax}}
    \fi
    \makecaption{\figurename#1~\thefigure\alph{subfigure} :}{~\normalfont#2}}

\newcommand{\nextsubcaption}[2][\empty]% #1 = short caption (optional), #2 = caption
{\refstepcounter{subfigure}
    \ifx#1\empty
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline {\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}{\ignorespaces #2 \relax}}
    \else
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline {\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}{\ignorespaces #1 \relax}}
    \fi
    \makecaption{\figurename#1~\thefigure\alph{subfigure} :}{~\normalfont#2}}
```

---

```
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@lofline{1}{0em}{5.5em}}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@lofline{1}{0em}{6em}}                     % {1}{0em}{5.5em}} - SBÖ
```

---

```
%======================================== LOF PAGE SETTINGS =========================================== - SBÖ  
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
    %\vspace*{\ChapterUstenBosluk}              % This is not effective - SBÖ
    {\chapter*{\listfigurename}
    \vspace*{-18pt}
    \renewcommand{\ULdepth}{4pt}                % Added using ulem package for \uline command - SBÖ
    \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.5pt}          % Added for underline tickness change which was 0.4pt - SBÖ
    \if@Ingilizce\hfill\vspace*{0truecm}{\bf\uline{Page}}~\else~\hfill\vspace*{0truecm}{\bf\uline{Sayfa}}\fi}\\ % Instead of \underline{text} - SBÖ
%\hfill\vspace*{0.5truecm}{\bf\underline{\if@Ingilizce Page\else Sayfa\fi}}}

    \let\orig@numberline\numberline
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{
    \orig@numberline{\bf\figurename\ ##1}\hspace{-8pt}{\bf:}\hspace{4pt}} % Better spacing - SBÖ
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bf{\protect\listfigurenameToC}}
    \setlength{\th@oldparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\LoFparskip}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\th@oldparskip}
    \let\numberline\orig@numberline
    }
```

The part below is related to `\makecaption`.

```
\newcommand{\makecaption}[2]% #1 = caption head, #2 = caption text
{\savebox{\tempbox}{#1#2}
    \ifdim\wd\tempbox>\textwidth
    \settowidth{\tempwidth}{#1}
    \savebox{\tempbox}{\parbox{\textwidth}
        {\hangindent=\tempwidth
            \hangafter=1
            \makebox[\tempwidth][l]{#1}#2}}
    \fi
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    {\centering\usebox{\tempbox}\par}
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip\hbox{}}
```

**What I want to do:**

I am not familiar with the class things in LaTex, I creates only basic documents. So, how can I remove this unwanted indent?

Thanks in advance.

.

Comment: Based on your comment, "I think it arose from the multiple lines in the caption since it disappeared in the case of a single line", it may be related to the definition of `\makecaption`, which you do not provide for your particular class.

Comment: please provide a usable test file but you are adding lots of probably unwanted white space in your definitions you should have a `%` at the end of every line ending in `{` or `}`

Comment: also note `\bf{\protect\listfigurenameToC}`  the command `\bf` is not defined by default, in classes where it is defined it does not take an argument so the syntax is `{\bf abc}`  not `\bf{abc}` but better to use `\bfseries`

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle. Appending `%` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at page xvii of the `thesis.pdf` file available in the İTÜ thesis template repository on github you will see this behavior beginning with the first caption spanning multiple lines (Table 2.3).

[image]

Appending `%` to the end of every line ending in `{` or `}` in `\renewcommand\listoftables{%` and `\renewcommand\listoffigures{%` appears to solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @dcsim, this solved the issue.

Comment: gule gule kullan @FurkanŞahin. I've submitted a PR to the repo you linked that implements a fix for the spacing issue.